# How to auto-layout the UIImageview base on its image size after downloading the image via SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout, sdwebimage

I built [a sample project](https://github.com/xingheng/UITableViewCell-Autolayout) hosted on GitHub.

There is a table view and its custom cell has a multiple line UILabel and a dynamic image view base on its image size. I built it step by step to verify the auto-layout issue on the custom cell.

In the 3rd sample table view (`Table3ViewController`) which has the above view structure, I tested it with sample random length text and local images. It succeeds, just like [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH25-SW1) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/1677041) said.

Actually, all the auto-layout tutorials or examples from google search results are tested base on the local image assets, no `SDWebImage` usage related, basically.

In `Table4ViewController`, the UIImageView/UITableViewCell(CustomCell) finished its subview's layout before the `SDWebImage` set the final image object to UIImageView asynchronously.

Here is my question, how to re-layout the UITableViewCell(CustomCell) after the `SDWebImage` downloaded the image from the network?

Here are my constraints within CustomCell.

```
    [label mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.top);
        make.centerX.width.equalTo(self.contentView);
        make.bottom.equalTo(imageView.top);
        make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(@16);
    }];

    [imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(label.bottom);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.bottom);
        make.centerX.width.equalTo(self.contentView);
        make.height.lessThanOrEqualTo(@200);
    }];
```

I tried to move the implementation to `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` or `updateConstraints` or `layoutSubviews` method, all the results are the same and failed.

Here is the image view assignment within `cellForRow` **without placeholder image**.

```
__weak __typeof(cell) weakCell = cell;

[cell.theImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dict.allValues.firstObject]
                            completed:^(UIImage *_Nullable image, NSError *_Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *_Nullable imageURL) {
      __strong __typeof(cell) strongCell = weakCell;

      [strongCell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
      [strongCell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
}];
```

Assume a network image has size 400x400 points, there is no reserved placeholder image in cell, the update constraint and layout subviews' request will be ready and finished asynchronously successfully. However, the new cell's height won't be recalculated into the contentSize of tableview, the draw process of CustomCell won't be called. It fails.

---

Here is the image view assignment within `cellForRow` **with placeholder image**.

```
__weak __typeof(cell) weakCell = cell;

[cell.theImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dict.allValues.firstObject]
                     placeholderImage:GetImageWithColor(DarkRandomColor, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame), 400)
                            completed:^(UIImage *_Nullable image, NSError *_Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *_Nullable imageURL) {
      __strong __typeof(cell) strongCell = weakCell;

      [strongCell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
      [strongCell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
}];
```

The final image will be drawn with the same size of reserved placeholder image finally, but I expected the final image's size even specified ratio.

So, how to re-layout the image view's size constraint after downloading the image asynchronously?

Comment: to be honest, your code is so right maybe it s about tableview. after completed action you should reload tableview

Comment: I tried to reload the cell after which the containing image is  finished downloading in main thread, the FPS is so low that  the swipe gesture is proximity hung. No luck. :(

Comment: And what do you want to see happen? Image to be much higher than placeholder or?

Comment: Show as the actual size of image.